# SynCrypto.pas and Lazarus compile problem

Tags: lazarus, mormot

I'm trying to use SynCrypto.pas (part of Synopse mORMot ORM/SOA/MVC framework) in my Lazarus project to decrypt AES-128 stream. My project not compiling with errors in SynFPCTypInfo at this code:

```
PFPCInterfaceData = TypInfo.PInterfaceData;
PFPCVmtMethodParam = TypInfo.PVmtMethodParam;
PFPCIntfMethodTable = TypInfo.PIntfMethodTable;
PFPCIntfMethodEntry = TypInfo.PIntfMethodEntry;

SynFPCTypInfo.pas(91,31) Error: Identifier not found "PInterfaceData"
SynFPCTypInfo.pas(91,45) Error: Error in type definition
SynFPCTypInfo.pas(92,32) Error: Identifier not found "PVmtMethodParam"
SynFPCTypInfo.pas(92,47) Error: Error in type definition
SynFPCTypInfo.pas(93,33) Error: Identifier not found "PIntfMethodTable"
SynFPCTypInfo.pas(93,49) Error: Error in type definition
SynFPCTypInfo.pas(94,33) Error: Identifier not found "PIntfMethodEntry"
SynFPCTypInfo.pas(94,49) Error: Error in type definition
```

I think that it's incompatibility with Delphi TypInfo module.  How can I fix it?

Comment: I added error descriptions

Answer (score 0):

So ... I suggest you to install the new pascal: https://github.com/newpascal/newpascal/releases/tag/np-v1.0.56, download the zip and unzip it in some folder, for example (D: \ lazarus \ newpascal), and configure the paths according to the mORMot site: For proper FPC compilation, ensure you have the following settings to your project:

Other unit files (-Fu):
D:\lazarus\newpascal\ccr\mORMot;D:\lazarus\newpascal\ccr\mORMot\SQLite3;D:\lazarus\newpascal\ccr\mORMot\SQLite3\DDD\infra\

Include files (-Fi):
$(ProjOutDir);D:\lazarus\newpascal\ccr\mORMot;D:\lazarus\newpascal\ccr\mORMot\SQLite3\

Libraries (-fFl):
D:\lazarus\newpascal\ccr\mORMot\static$(TargetCPU)-$(TargetOS)\

site: https: //synopse.info/files/html/Synopse%20mORMot%20Framework%20SAD%201.18.html#TITL_113, then you will have at least how to test your app.